# Setting up log shipping with an availability group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, log-shipping

In my production environment I have a SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn AG.

The Server1 there is database "MessagesDB" and in an AG to secondary Server2 (in synchronous mode).

I want to setup log shipping from Server1.MessagesDB to a data warehouse (Server3).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Robert Douglas](http://gumption.co.nz/2-about-me/) describes the exact solution to my problem in his post:

[Why log shipping backups fail in an Always On Availability Group – Resolved](http://gumption.co.nz/2013/11/why-log-shipping-backups-fail-in-an-always-on-availability-group-resolved/)

Robert writes:

> ...the availability group was trying to enforce a backup being taken off the secondary replica, and the log shipping job didn’t like that.
>
> Here's how to correct it.
>
> 1. In Management Studio expand AlwaysOn High Availability and then Availability Groups.
> 2. Right click on your chosen group and choose properties.
> 3. In the left pane select backup preferences.
> 4. Select 'Primary' as your backup source.  Click Okay.

Comment: I have improved your self-answer to be more than just a link, and added the required [attribution](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). You may accept your own answer by clicking the check mark.